# Update Solr with Nifi

Tags: solr, apache-nifi

I have a Nifi workflow which retrieves a URL from Solr and calculates the share count of this URL on different social media's, I need to update this share count back on Solr, the two attributes in the flowfile are the url and the respective sharecount, how can I do the update back to solr with Nifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PutSolrContentStream processor to insert a new document into Solr, or overwrite one that is there. There currently isn't support for partial updates, so if you were trying to update a document that was already there, then you need to have the entire original document in NiFi + the updates, so you can send the whole document back in.

PutSolrContentStream can basically do any of the updates described here:

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html

The default approach is to create a JSON document in NiFi and send that to the JSON update handler.